# How to schedule mac codesign nightly (cron/launchd)?

Tags: macos, cron, launchd, codesign

I need to schedule Apple's `codesign` tool to run nightly on a macOS machine.

I have tried both cron and launchd but cannot get either to work correctly. I've tried many many things now... and I really don't care which I use as long as it works.

**NOTE**: My user account is a non-administrative account and I do not have root access. If there is a solution that requires root access, I am still interested to hear about it, but it won't fix my immediate problem!

Can anyone PLEASE help make this work with one or the other?

---

**My attempt with cron**

My User's crontab:

```
00 01 * * * /Users/user175695/test.sh > $HOME/test.log 2>&1
```

My `test.sh` script with plenty of security debugging output:

```
set -e
set -x

security unlock-keychain -p "my-password" /Users/user175695/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db

echo "USER=$(whoami)"

security list-keychains
security list-keychains -d user
security default-keychain
security login-keychain
security show-keychain-info

security list-keychains -d user -s /Users/user175695/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db
security unlock-keychain -p "my-password" /Users/user175695/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db
security default-keychain -s /Users/user175695/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db

security list-keychains
security list-keychains -d user
security default-keychain
security login-keychain
security show-keychain-info


/usr/bin/codesign --keychain /Users/user175695/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db -s "Developer ID Application: My Name" -f --verbose /Users/user175695/my.app
```

Results of my `test.sh` script in `test.log`:

```
security unlock-keychain -p my-password /Users/user175695/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db
++ whoami
+ echo USER=user175695
USER=user175695
+ security list-keychains
    "/Library/Keychains/System.keychain"
    "/Library/Keychains/System.keychain"
+ security list-keychains -d user
    "/Library/Keychains/System.keychain"
+ security default-keychain
    "/Library/Keychains/System.keychain"
+ security login-keychain
    "/Library/Keychains/System.keychain"
+ security show-keychain-info
Keychain "<NULL>" lock-on-sleep timeout=300s
+ security list-keychains -d user -s /Users/user175695/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db
+ security unlock-keychain -p my-password /Users/user175695/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db
+ security default-keychain -s /Users/user175695/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db
+ security list-keychains
    "/Library/Keychains/System.keychain"
    "/Library/Keychains/System.keychain"
+ security list-keychains -d user
    "/Library/Keychains/System.keychain"
+ security default-keychain
    "/Library/Keychains/System.keychain"
+ security login-keychain
    "/Library/Keychains/System.keychain"
+ security show-keychain-info
Keychain "<NULL>" lock-on-sleep timeout=300s

+ /usr/bin/codesign --keychain /Users/user175695/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db -s 'Developer ID Application: My Name' -f --verbose /Users/user175695/my.app
error: The specified item could not be found in the keychain.
```

At first glance the problem appears to be that the identify can't be found in the keychain `/Users/user175695/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db`. The identity is actually in the keychain, but the man page for `codesign` says:

> Note that filename will not be searched to resolve the signing identity's certificate chain unless it is also on the user's keychain search list.

We can see from `test.log` that the keychain `login.keychain-db` is not in the keychain search list. The call to `security list-keychains -d user -s /Users/user175695/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db`, should remedy that... however that command is returning 0 exit code whilst doing nothing :-(

The `test.sh` script runs fine when run from an SSH session to the Mac machine, but does not run correctly from `cron`. Is there anything I can do to remedy this in Mac cron?

---

**My attempt with launchd**

I found many articles where people have similar problems with `codesign` and Mac's cron, and some of them suggested that switching to launchd was a viable workaround.

The problem I am seeing with launchd is that my launchd User Agent only runs whilst I am logged in to the Mac GUI (via RemoteDesktop). It does not work when I am logged in only via SSH or when I am logged out. That is obviously of no use for an automated nightly build.

My launchd user agent - `~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.evolvedbinary.afterdark.test.plist`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>com.evolvedbinary.afterdark.test</string>
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
            <string>/bin/bash</string>
            <string>/Users/user175695/test.sh</string>
        </array>
        <key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
        <!-- Run every day at 01:00 -->
        <dict>
            <key>Hour</key>
            <integer>01</integer>
            <key>Minute</key>
            <integer>00</integer>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

Can launchd user-agents which have a scheduled interval run when the user is logged-out? If so, what am I missing?